# Room Database Migration doesnt properly handle ALTER TABLE migration

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

> Java.lang.IllegalStateException
>
> Migration didn't properly handle
> user(therealandroid.github.com.roomcore.java.User).
>
> Expected:
>
> TableInfo{name='user', columns={name=Column{name='name', type='TEXT',
> notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, age=Column{name='age',
> type='INTEGER', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0},
> id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', notNull=true,
> primaryKeyPosition=1}}, foreignKeys=[]}   Found:
>
> Found
>
> TableInfo{ name='user', columns={name=Column{name='name', type='TEXT',
> notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, id=Column{name='id',
> type='INTEGER', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1},
> age=Column{name='age', type='INTEGER', notNull=false,
> primaryKeyPosition=0}}, foreignKeys=[]}

I'm trying to perform a simple migration, I have a class called `User`and it have two columns `ID (primary key)` and `NAME TEXT` and then I populate database with two users data, then I add the column `AGE` in the object `User` and in the Migration constant I add an `alter table` to add this new column and lastly I replace version of the database 1 to 2.

Here is the code

User.class

```
@Entity(tableName = "user")
  public class User {

  @PrimaryKey
  private int id;

  @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
  private String name;

  @ColumnInfo(name = "age")
  private int age;


  public int getId() {
      return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
      this.id = id;
  }

  public String getName() {
      return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
  }

  public int getAge() {
      return age;
  }

  public void setAge(int age) {
      this.age = age;
  }
}
```

Database class

```
@Database(entities = {User.class}, version = 2)
public abstract class RoomDatabaseImpl extends RoomDatabase {
    abstract UserDao userDao();
}
```

Migration code

```
public static Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE 'user' ADD COLUMN 'age' INTEGER");
    }
 };
```

and it call

```
Room.databaseBuilder(context, RoomDatabaseImpl.class, "Sample.db")
            .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)
            .allowMainThreadQueries()
            .build();
```

Before change the object adding `AGE` and performing the migration I add two register and it works.

After performing the migration, I just tried to add a new User as bellow:

```
  User user = new User();
  user.setName("JoooJ");
  user.setId(3);
  user.setAge(18);

  List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();
  userList.add(user);
  App.database(this).userDao().insertAll(userList);  // The crash happens here
```

Other informations:

Android Studio 3 and I didn't tested in the actual.

Dependencies:

```
compile "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-alpha9-1"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha9-1"

compile "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:1.0.0-alpha9-1"
gradle 2.3.3
```

Can someone help me please, I realy don't know what im doing wrong or if it is a bug.

Comment: A bit of a shot in the dark, but perhaps try `"ALTER TABLE 'user' ADD COLUMN 'age' INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0"` (0 could be whatever you consider suitable).

Comment: Room expects the column order to match the field order. It would appear that the results of the `ALTER TABLE` are resulting in a different order.

Comment: Check bellow answer. It has complete description:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51245898/3073945

Comment: @CommonsWare What determines the column ordering?

Comment: @Skj: It has been a few years since I worked with Room, but IIRC, the columns are in the order that the properties are in your entity class. You can always look at the generated SQL or the database that Room creates to see the column order.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

The error message is hard to parse, but there's a difference:

> TableInfo{name='user', columns={name=Column{name='name', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, age=Column{name='age', type='INTEGER', ***notNull=true***, primaryKeyPosition=0}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1}}, foreignKeys=[]} Found:

Found

> TableInfo{ name='user', columns={name=Column{name='name', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1}, age=Column{name='age', type='INTEGER', ***notNull=false***, primaryKeyPosition=0}}, foreignKeys=[]}

Age is nullable but Room expected it to be not null.

Change your migration to:

```
database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE 'user' ADD COLUMN 'age' INTEGER NOT NULL");
```

---

Since this exception explanation is VERY difficult to parse, I have created [a small script](https://gist.github.com/BenoitDuffez/aa4555926df5360e1be2eafee0f79784) that does the diff for you.

Example:

```
mig "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration failed. expected:TableInfo{name='user', columns={name=Column{name='name', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, age=Column{name='age', type='INTEGER', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1}}, foreignKeys=[]} , found:TableInfo{name='user', columns={name=Column{name='name', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1}, age=Column{name='age', type='INTEGER', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}}, foreignKeys=[]}"
```

Result:

[image: expected/found diff]

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks for helping. 
And now I understand, when you perform migrations, you must specify the DEFAULT value for the new column to be populated.

Comment: Try your migrations on a dummy database and see if the query does what you expect it to do.

Comment: I also found something interesting: if you created indices in your @Entity annotation in your model, you need to also do it in SQL in your migration script, for example `CREATE  INDEX `index_History_nodeId` ON `History` (`nodeId`)`
and if you don't you'll get a `Migration didn't properly handle`

Comment: Hi I am getting this error for Expected type='TEXT' and Found type='nvarchar'. How to represent type='nvarchar' in Java?

Comment: Please add  default 'some_default_value' for the added column at the end in alter query otherwise you would get other exception related to migration like 'Cannot add a NOT NULL column with default value NULL'

Answer (score 48):

I too wrote a small JS script which you can find https://hrankit.github.io/RoomSQLiteDifferenceFinder/

The process is pretty Simple.

1. Input the Expected error log in Expected column which is the Left One.
2. Input the Found error log in Found column which is the Right One.
3. Press Go. button. The error logs get converted to JSON.
4. Press Compare button and Voila, you have the difference you need.

This plugin finds out the difference in the two Expected and Found dump from the Android Studio Logcat.

Checkout the image of comparison here

[image]

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @HRankit Just Awesome, your script solved my problem.

Comment: this tool is not working now, can u pls recheck it ?

Comment: @RiteshAdulkar What about if the existing sqlite table has VARCHAR columns and the new table has TEXT instead. Will it make difference while migrating ?

Comment: Hi @HRankit I appreciate the tool but I am unable to get it to see that my paste is legitimate.  It is kicked out with the same error message that I am supposed to paste in a particular format.  Can you give more debugging information when a paste fails?

Comment: @HRankit This tool is not working now, although I have entered legit data. It throws an error that "Json Invalid Please paste from Expected TableInfo".

Answer (score 27):

None of the answers are correct in any of the links. After much experiments, found a way for it. The ALTER query needs to be written in the following way to make it work:

```
database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE 'user' ADD COLUMN 'age' INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0")
```

However, the Integer DEFAULT value can be anything.

If you want to add String type column, add in the following manner:

```
database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE 'user' ADD COLUMN 'address' TEXT")
```

This works like a charm.

Comment: can i add default value to String column?

Answer (score 7):

I faced this issue today, I just changed `int` fields to `Integer` in `Entities`. As `int` cannot be null but `Integer` objects could be null.

Comment: Caused a separate issue of `error: incomparable types: int and <null>` for me oddly enough

Answer (score 5):

if you want to add Integer type column , add this code

```
database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE users"
                    + " ADD COLUMN year INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ")
```

Answer (score 2):

The tool mentioned by @HRankit in his answer: [link](https://hrankit.github.io/RoomSQLiteDifferenceFinder/) did not seem to work when I tried it today. If that is the case for you too, please read on:

If anyone is struggling with error message mentioned in the question and have a huge table with lots of columns, you might want to try [this](https://www.diffchecker.com/) online tool to check between expected and found schema.

Also its really important that you decide upon the column names and data types before the `<db_version_number>.json` (eg: `13.json`) file is generated. If the json file was already generated and you made some changes to the Entity class afterwards, you might want to delete the json file and rebuild the project to generate it with correct set of values.

Lastly you should check your sql statements on the migration itself.

Comment: The difference checker link actually helped to compare Expected and Found DB schema. Note: When altering a table with "Boolean" column as a new column then you have to use INTEGER in ALTER command. Refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55304942/5582162

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting notNull differences, you can simply mark your class field with @NonNull annotation, or change your sql with ALTER TABLE. But if you are getting column type differences, such as expected: TYPE=TEXT, then found TYPE='' (COLLATE NOCASE), or expected INTEGER, found INT, then the only solution is to drop and recreate your table. Sqlite does not allow changing column types.

Use INTEGER in Sqlite instead of INT and mark your Java entity with @ColumnInfo(collate = NOCASE) (if you use NOCASE in Sqlite).

Take a look at the json file under app\schemas to get the sql for the expected queries.

```
static final Migration MIGRATION_2_3= new Migration(2, 3) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {

            database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_tmp");

            database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_tmp` ...");

            database.execSQL("insert into table_tmp (`id`, `name` , ...");

            database.execSQL("DROP INDEX IF EXISTS `index_table_name`");

            database.execSQL("CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS `index_table_name` ON `table_tmp` (`name`)");

            database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table");

            database.execSQL("alter table table_tmp rename to table");

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced notNull differences in kotlin and found exception like below

```
Expected:
TableInfo{name='enDic', columns={definition=Column{name='definition', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, _id=Column{name='_id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, favourite=Column{name='favourite', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, word=Column{name='word', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, usage=Column{name='usage', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
Found:
TableInfo{name='enDic', columns={usage=Column{name='usage', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, definition=Column{name='definition', type='text', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, _id=Column{name='_id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, favourite=Column{name='favourite', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, word=Column{name='word', type='text', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
```

Then I used below mentioned code to solve that problem

```
@Entity(tableName = "enDic")
data class Word(

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "_id")
    var _id: Int?,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "word")
    var word: String?,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "definition")
    var definition: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "favourite")
    var favourite: Int?,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "usage")
    var usage: Int?

)
```

Instead of this code

```
@Entity(tableName = "enDic")
data class Word(

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "_id")
    var _id: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "word")
    var word: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "definition")
    var definition: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "favourite")
    var favourite: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "usage")
    var usage: Int

)
```

Comment: what is the difference between both @Entity classes

Comment: @Nilabja I used _id, word, favourite and usage columns with null variable type. you can see `?` symbol

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with roomVersion '2.4.0-alpha01', this version not generate Index table for my case

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "SoundRules",
    indices = [
        Index(value = ["remoteId"], unique = true)
    ]
)
```

I resolve problem just updated room version to '2.4.0-alpha03'

Answer (score 0):

if you have notNull true and false issue, it can be solved in two ways

1. Change the types of @Entity class variables to null to NotNull typs or vice-versa  using **?** eg **String? Int?**

   `val name: String?, // to use with null type column`
2. Add/remove NOT NULL after column name

   `database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE` Fruit `(`id`INTEGER,`name `TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`id`))")`

Make to sure to match Entity param type(nullable or nonnull) with Column type

```
String -> NOT NULL

String? -> NULL (//default type in sqlite, no need to mention it)
```